# how to use number field like query in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

schema like

```
mobileNo: {
  type: Number,
  trim: true,
}
```

i don't know how to like query in mongodb on number field not on STRING

Comment: Mongodb doesn't give you flexibility for pattern matching on numbers. for that u need to store the number as string.

Comment: Can u please provide sample data that you store?

Comment: Can you add what exactly you are trying to get out as a result? What you have provided is hardly enough to get the whole picture.